# header duplicate symbol c

Tags: c++, header, duplicates

I've recently been trying to learn myself to use QT and as part of an exercise I've set up some simple stuff for managing a deck of cards (adding and removing cards by dragging and dropping and other simple stuff like that). However as you might imagine, it's not going as smoothly as I'd have hoped it would. To implement this logic I've used 3 classes, Card, Node and Pile which all have their own headers with prototypes on what you can do with them.

The issue here is that when I try to compile them the compiler starts complaining about duplicate symbols in the object file concerning the functions of different classes. If I comment one away with "/* */" the problem only moves one function "down the line" and the only things the compiler doesn't complain about are the destructors. Here's what it says more specifically whenever I try to compile:

```
duplicate symbol Node::Node(*Card) in Node.o and Node.o
```

This is what the (.hpp) header looks like:

```
#ifndef NODE_HPP
#define NODE_HPP
#include "Card.hpp"
class Node{
      Node *next;
      Card *c;
public:
      Node() { }
      Node(Card *newCard);
      ~Node();
      Node *getNext();
      void appendNode(Card *newCard);
      void printCard();

      void setNext(Node *nextNode);
      Card *getCard(); //Returns card in node (with removal)
      Card *peekCard(); //Returns card in node (without removal)
};

#endif //NODE_HPP
```

...and this is what the actual .cpp-file looks like:

```
#include "Node.hpp"
#include "Card.hpp"

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

Node::Node(Card *newCard){
    c = newCard;
    next = NULL;
}

Node::~Node(){
    free(c);
    delete this;
}

Node* Node::getNext(){
    return next;
}

void Node::appendNode(Card *newCard){
    if(next == NULL){
        next = new Node(newCard);
    }
    else{
        Node* NodePointer = next;
        while((NodePointer->getNext()) != NULL){
            NodePointer = NodePointer->getNext();
        }
        NodePointer->next = new Node(newCard);
    }
}

void Node::printCard(){
    c->printCard();
}

void Node::setNext(Node *nextNode){
    next = nextNode;
}

Card* Node::getCard(){
    return c;
    c = NULL;
}

Card* Node::peekCard(){
    return c;
}
```

So I'm essentially now out of ideas about what could be wrong as I've tried everything I could think of and in my opinion, the code should be ok as no matter how hard I try to look, I can't see anything wrong with it. So as Google searches and searches at a bunch of other sites didn't turn out anything, I'm now turning to stackoverflow as you code wizards with plenty more experience should have a better eye for spotting out (what I atleast think are) newbie mistakes.

Comment: My guess is that you have two different files both called Node.cpp in different directories which are both getting compiled in your project.

Comment: Off-topic advice: there is no need to include "Card.hpp" in "Node.hpp". You're using pointers to `Card` in the header, so just forward declare `class Card`.

Comment: Also, in the destructor of `Node`: 1) there is no need to `delete this`. 2) That `free(c)` looks fishy. Where did you `malloc` it? And if you did, why `malloc` instead of `new`?

Comment: Thanks Paul R, because you just helped me find the problem. The problem was that the .pro-file had two entries of "Node.cpp" and "Pile.cpp" in the SOURCES part. Also, ElitanT, that is actually a bit dumb and delete c does fit better as I use "new" rather than malloc (I guess I should blame my background in C for that mistake). So thanks for the advice and the problem has just been solved.